# javascript function that changes the orientation of a device

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a desktop application that assists in posting story on instagram, but I'm facing a problem. I use a cell phone simulation to open instagram, and to post instagram, it asks me to rotate the device. I've tried everything, but nothing works. I would like to know if there is any javascript function that changes the device orientation.

[image]

Comment: Rotate your simulated device? Please share more details of what you are simulating and how.

Comment: the most meaningful thing would be having such option inside the tool simulating the device. By the way the most adopted web browser, Chrome, has such feature in the developer tools where you can choose to see the current page simulating any viewport size (with device examples) and with an additional trigger to put it landscape. Unfortunately that's not the tool you are supposed to use in your case.

Comment: i added an image that should give more details.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't explain how you are simulating a mobile device. Please add details of how your code works (Or better, a minimal example of the code itself)

Answer (score 1):

With the JavaScript Function

```
screen.orientation.lock("portrait")
```

or

```
screen.orientation.lock("landscape")
```

you can Rotate the Device in the Web View